# can switch case will wait for await result

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

```
async function getUsers(type,doc){   
  switch(type){

      case "requserlist" :
        let ids = await Users.find({_id:{$in:{doc.ids}}}).distinct('user_id').exec();
          return {'_id':{'$in':ids},'login_status':{$ne:false}};
 
       default  : //allusers
      // console.log('final deafult');
        return {'is_active':true'login_status':true};      
  }
}
//=========================================================================
    getUsers(type,doc).then(conditions=>{
      // console.log('-----------------------',conditions);
})
```

when it enters into `CASE` "requserlist" , will switch case will wait till it gets all users ids , or will it goes to default CASE when it take much time to fetch results from await.
if i use timeouts there it gives undefined result,
can u tell us valuable suggestions Thank you

Comment: It will do whatever the matching `case` says to do. If it goes to the first case it will wait, otherwise it won't.

Comment: if `type` is `"requserlist"`, then execution will not ever go to the `default` case. It is hard to tell what your problem is. Why would you introduce setTimeouts?

Comment: `{doc.ids}` isn't valid syntax... also I'm having a hard time understanding your question. What is the problem you're having?

Comment: i thought it will return ,before query fetching data

Answer (score 1):

This is how `switch case` works example.

```js
async function TSwitch(st) {
    switch(st) {
        case 'checked':
            console.log('checked');
            break;
        case 'unchecked':
            console.log('unchecked');
            await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000));
            console.log('after promise');
            break;
    }
}

TSwitch('checked');
TSwitch('unchecked');
```